# Trying to solve date difference start with zero

Tags: javascript, jquery

Implemented start date and end date to find the day difference. If i select start date today and end date today then difference is showing that 0 and i have disabled the weekends though its counting the weekends also. Here is my code.
What i have tried to solve:

1. When i select same day date ex: start date: 16-08-2018 end date: 16-08-2018 it showing 0 in the date difference. But i need to show 1
2. Weekends disabled but when i select 10 days between start date and end date then its calculating weekends also. I tried to solve both these but didn't happen

```js
$("#startDate").datepicker({

  beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
  changeMonth: true,
  todayHighlight: true,

  minDate: 0,
  numberOfMonths: 1,
  todayHighlight: true,
  weekStart: 1,
  weekEnd: 5,
  onSelect: function(dateStr) {
    var min = $(this).datepicker('getDate'); // Get selected date
    $("#endDate").datepicker('option', 'minDate', min || '0'); // Set other min, default to today
  }
});

$("#endDate").datepicker({

  beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
  changeMonth: true,
  endDate: true,
  todayHighlight: true,
  minDate: 0,
  numberOfMonths: 1,
  weekStart: 1,
  weekEnd: 5,
  buttonImageOnly: true,
  onSelect: function(dateStr) {



    var max = $(this).datepicker('getDate'); // Get selected date
    $('#datepicker').datepicker('option', 'maxDate');
    var start = $("#startDate").datepicker("getDate");
    var end = $("#endDate").datepicker("getDate");
    var days = (end - start) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
    $("#noofDays").val(days);

  }
});
```

```html
<link href="css/jquery.ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-md-12" style="padding-top: 1px;">Start Date<span class="text" style="color: red;">*</span></label>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-12">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="startDate" id="startDate" placeholder="Start Date" required/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-md-12" style="padding-top: 1px;">End Date<span class="text" style="color: red;">*</span></label>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-12">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="endDate" id="endDate" placeholder="End Date" required/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-md-12" style="padding-top: 1px;"> No of Days<span class="text" style="color: red;">*</span></label>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-12">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="noofDays" id="noofDays" placeholder="No of days" required/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I done it as runnable. When i select start date as today and end date as today it showing the value 0. And top of that it counting weekends too.

Comment: If you select today and tomorrow, do you want 2 or 1 (do you want to include both the start day and the end day)? And way you don't disable the fiedl "No. of Days"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to include both the start and the end date you should add one to `days`, and for solve the problem with weekends, I iterate over the days between the start and the end and subtract one from the days number (the variable `days`), if the current day is a weekend day.

```js
$("#startDate").datepicker({

  beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
  changeMonth: true,
  todayHighlight: true,

  minDate: 0,
  numberOfMonths: 1,
  todayHighlight: true,
  weekStart: 1,
  weekEnd: 5,
  onSelect: function(dateStr) {
    var min = $(this).datepicker('getDate'); // Get selected date
    $("#endDate").datepicker('option', 'minDate', min || '0'); // Set other min, default to today
  }
});

$("#endDate").datepicker({

  beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
  changeMonth: true,
  endDate: true,
  todayHighlight: true,
  minDate: 0,
  numberOfMonths: 1,
  weekStart: 1,
  weekEnd: 5,
  buttonImageOnly: true,
  onSelect: function(dateStr) {



    var max = $(this).datepicker('getDate'); // Get selected date
    $('#datepicker').datepicker('option', 'maxDate');
    var start = $("#startDate").datepicker("getDate");
    var end = $("#endDate").datepicker("getDate");
    var days = ((end - start) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) + 1; // Add one to include the end day
    for (var dayBetween = start; dayBetween <= end; dayBetween.setDate(dayBetween.getDate() + 1)) {
      var dayOfWeek = dayBetween.getDay();
      if (0 === dayOfWeek || 6 === dayOfWeek) { // Weekend day
        days--;
      }
    }
    $("#noofDays").val(days);

  }
});
```

```html
<link href="css/jquery.ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-md-12" style="padding-top: 1px;">Start Date<span class="text" style="color: red;">*</span></label>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-12">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="startDate" id="startDate" placeholder="Start Date" required/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-md-12" style="padding-top: 1px;">End Date<span class="text" style="color: red;">*</span></label>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-12">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="endDate" id="endDate" placeholder="End Date" required/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-md-12" style="padding-top: 1px;"> No of Days<span class="text" style="color: red;">*</span></label>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-12">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="noofDays" id="noofDays" placeholder="No of days" required/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```